# Scikit-learn: can we have dynamic parameters based on data for grid search

Tags: dynamic, parameters, dependencies, scikit-learn, grid-search

I am performing a grid search using the "seuclidean" metric. The parameters of this metric that are passed to the grid search are:

```
seuclidean        = {'metric': ['seuclidean'], 
                     'metric_params':[ {'V':V} ], 
                     'algorithm': ['brute', 'ball_tree'], 
                     'n_neighbors': list(k_range), 'weights': weights, 
                     'leaf_size': list(leaf_sizes) }
```

Now `k_range` and `leaf_size` are lists that are independent of the data used. However in the `metric_params':[ {'V':V} ]`, the `V`is the variance that is usually calculated as follows:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
                                           X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=1)
V = X.var().values
```

However, I am normalizing the data prior to estimation. More concretely I am using a pipeline for this:

```
pipe = Pipeline([ 
                 ('standardize', preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()),
                 ('sfs', sfs1), 
                 ('knn', knn)])
```

(note: 'sfs' does feature and parameter selections). In such a setting I assume that we need to calculate the variance vector based on the data-set that is actually passed onto the estimator for training and validation.

So my question is: how do I perform the calculation and setting of the `V` parameter dynamically on the training data after the split has been made? Is this possible? If not, how should I go about setting these "data dependent"
parameters?

TIA.

Comment: It's not clear how-why the V parameter is used. What does it do? Is it something you need to perform grid search on or is it just a value that differs with each train-test split?

Comment: No, you do not have to do a grid search on it. It simply the variance of the training data. It allows the distance metric to be weighted.

Comment: OK then V should not be on the grid search params. I would 'break' the pipeline to include only the first two steps. I would fit_transform the data, then calculate V for the resulting training dataset and pass V on to KNN. This means you have to do the CV yourself (i.e. without GridSearchCV). Does it makes sense?

Comment: Yes it makes sense. However, the whole objective is to use GridSearchCV or the random variant of this function. I was hopping GridSearchCV provided a way to inject changes to the parameters that it passed on to the pipe. Thanks for the feedback though. Appreciate it.